# How do I get all the SQL Server views names that have "SELECT * FROM..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

In order to identify high risk views when making changes to underlying tables and be able to do `sp_refreshview`, I'd like to get the names of all views that are querying all (*) the columns from a table using the `SELECT *`

For example, find views with cases like:

```
SELECT *
SELECT SomeAlias.*
```

Note:
I understand that `SELECT *` is a bad practice and strongly not [recommended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117394/are-there-issues-with-using-select-in-a-view-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS ObjectName,
       o.type_desc ObjectType,
       SUBSTRING (m.definition, PATINDEX ( '%[.][*]%' , m.definition )-4, 20) MatchedPattern
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE  m.definition Like '%[.][*]%'
 AND o.type_desc  IN ('VIEW')
```